# How to create html/aspx page on button click which holds database fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I wish to create a dynamic `aspx` or `HTML` page on button click, and that page will have the database fields values using Asp.net and C#.

Is it possible to create such dynamic page on button click?

Comment: google it, you will get bunch of articles for this topic..

Comment: simple answer : Yes it is possible. [This link will give you several options](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create%20dynamic%20html%20page%20using%20c%23)

Comment: this is just a link of google,here i wants to create html within the c# code and i also wants to bind database values to that html

Answer (score 1):

The technology under the hood is to use Response.Write("xxx"). So, yes, you can make use of it to create a page.

e.g.

```
Response.Write("<html><head></head><body>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</body></html>")
```